# Safari change the color of the Background (search bar)

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-website

When visiting my website on safari it shows a purple pink color in the background/ behind the search bar.

[image]

How can I turn this off or change the color using html/css/js?

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying this only happens when you visit your site?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, every other site the color is the same as what i would expect to be the background color but mine is purple for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the answer:

Using

```html
<meta content="#bcbbff" data-react-helmet="true" name="theme-color" />
```

we can change the color of Safari's background.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the user's browser, sorry. If this is your phone you can probably change the browser theme in your settings, but this will only apply to your client.

Comment: I don't believe it's on the user's side though. I could be wrong but it's only when visiting my specific site. If I go to another one of my domains or another website the color is back to normal. Not sure how Safari gets the color to set it as the background. and I know it's not a setting that I set in my browser.